# how to sum a variable by group in r and display in a tabular form?

Tags: r, rstudio

Say I have this data:

```
User 1  User 2  Duration
5       2       7-11 months
5       5       Less than 1 month
5       5       4-6 months
5       5       4-6 months
5       4       4-6 months
5       5       2 years
4       6       1 year
4       4       4-6 months
4       8       7-11 months
4       4       2 years
3       3       Less than 1 month
3       3       7-11 months
3       3       1-3 months
```

To sum the variable, for example, if I would like to calculate `user1` within 4-6 months, I did that. Now, I would like to display all the individual values like:

```
       4-6 months  7-11 months  1-3 months
User1    values      values       values
User2    values      values       values
```

How do I get this kind of output?

Until now I have used this:

```
df %>% group_by(Duration) %>% summarise(count=sum(User1, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
filter(Duration=="4-6 months")
```

Comment: You'll get more eyeballs on this question if you take it to http://stackoverflow.com/ where it is also on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `xtabs()` function. [Here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.4.1/topics/xtabs) are some examples.